# Why doesn't address(this).balance work in a state variable?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

If we put `address(this).balance` inside a function, like this:

```
function getBalance() public view returns(uint) {
    return address(this).balance;
  }
```

It works perfectly as it should.

However, it doesn't work in a state variable:

```
 uint public balance = address(this).balance;
```

It always outputs 0.
Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uint public balance = address(this).balance;
```

sets the balance state variable to the the address' balance at the time the contract is created, which is 0. It will not update its value unless some function call explicitly updates its value.